# Django unit testing - assertRaises working when it shouldn't

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unit-testing

I was code reviewing an API and I found this in a unit test. The test passes but I can't understand why.

```
class SomeTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    @mock.patch("patch.a.thing", mock_function)
    def test_fail(self):
        request_data = {
            "some": "bad data"
        }

        response = self.client.post(
            "/path/to/api",
            json.dumps(request_data),
            content_type="application/json",
            HTTP_HEADERNAME=HEADER_VALUE
        )

        self.assertRaises(Exception, response)
```

We're expecting a 500 status code from the API as we're passing in bad data. Even if calling the API were to cause an exception, would that not be raise during the `client.post` casing the unit test to error? `response` is not a callable and therefore it is wrong to pass it to `assertRaises`, however the behaviour I would expect to see is that `assertRaises` does not get an exception and therefore the unit test fails. Can anyone explain why it behaves this way?

Edit:

I just tested this and this unit test passes as well:

```
class ThingTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_thing_fails(self):
        x = True
        y = False
        z = {"some": "thing"}

        self.assertRaises(Exception, x)
        self.assertRaises(Exception, y)
        self.assertRaises(Exception, z)
        self.assertRaises(Exception)
```

Comment: Since you call `response = self.client.post(...)` *before* your assertion, it looks as if that is not raising the expected exception. That suggests that your monkeypatching is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass a callable to `assertRaises`:

```
self.assertRaises(Exception, self.client.post,
        "/path/to/api",
        json.dumps(request_data),
        content_type="application/json",
        HTTP_HEADERNAME=HEADER_VALUE
)
```

It might be clearer to use it as a context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(Exception)
    response = self.client.post(
        "/path/to/api",
        json.dumps(request_data),
        content_type="application/json",
        HTTP_HEADERNAME=HEADER_VALUE
    )
```

At the moment, `self.assertRaises(Exception, response)` will try to call `response`, which raises `TypeError` because it isn't callable. Because you are calling `assertRaises` with `Exception`, the test passes. It's recommended to use a more specific error (e.g. `ValueError`) rather than `Exception`, to avoid issues like this. For example,

```
    x = True
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, x)
```

will fail, because calling `x` raises `TypeError`.